# Is there a way to limit a script to only be used by a single game object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My code for a singleton pattern

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Component
{
    private static T instance;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this as T;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);   
        }
    }
}
```

If I have multiple objects with a script that inherits from the singleton class, it will get destroyed and only one object will remain.
What I want is, if there is a way to limit the usage of the script. Like if the script is already attached to a gameobject, you can no longer use it for another one neither from the inspector nor using drag and drop.

Comment: no. You can limit the amount on the same GameObject via [`[DisallowMultipleComponent]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/DisallowMultipleComponent.html) but there is no (trivial) way to limit the usage on other objects ... also how would you deal with prefabs and multiple scenes? ;) The non-trivial way would be to let your code [`[ExecuteInEditMode]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html) possibly resulting in the amazing(not!) behavior that your Gameobject might get destroyed as soon as you attach a certain component ^^ ... you see what I mean I hope ;)

Comment: I would add a static reference to the gameObject to which it is attached. Instead of destroying the gameObject when the reference is not null, just remove the script component.

Comment: OK, but _why_ do you want to do this?

Comment: @TheBatman the question about how to deal with prefabs and different scenes stays the same though ;)

Comment: No got your position , but why you add this script to objects if not needed? Add this only to the needed object. Or make a condition to turn off the script in the gameobjects you like.